# Calling thread create function in C

Tags: c, multithreading

If I use the pthread_create() call in an infinite while loop in main, does it create multiple threads each time or will it only create the 2 threads that I need?

```
while(1){ 
   pthread_create(&thread_1...);
   pthread_create(&thread_2...);
}
```

Comment: Why loop if you only need two threads?  If you want your loop to wait for both threads to complete and then run again, you need a pair of `pthread_join()` calls in the loop after the calls to `pthread_create()` and you can keep the loop.  As it stands, you continually create threads until the system runs out of resources (and then your loop continues, failing to create threads).  However, you've lost track of all except the last two threads created — you keep overwriting the thread IDs, throwing away the previous values.

Answer (score 1):

it creates multiple threads each time.

Comment: Is there any way to create just the 2 threads and continuously call its function until a user signal?

Comment: run the thread function(s) in `while(1)` loop and install a signal handler in the main function

Comment: @sravs How can I exit the `while(1)` loop in the thread functions and return to the main function?

Comment: why `NULL` you said signal, install a handler for `SIGINT` or `SIGALRM` etc and for first one you need to press `CTRL+C` and for second you need to specify some timeout

Comment: @sravs Not sure what you meant by "why `NULL` you said signal". Could you please clarify?

Comment: I think you deleted the comment where you said wanted to return `NULL`

Comment: @sravs I have the function in the `while(1)` loop, but I'm stumped on getting back to main even with the `SIGINT` handler. Basically, I'm not sure what condition I need to put in the handler function to return to main.

Comment: @HMD answered , may be that is help full , checkout.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `pthread_cancel` to cancel any thread from the process.

Below is one of many ways to handle the termination of thread upon some event/timeout etc..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h> // for sigaction
#include <stdlib.h> // for exit and 
#include <pthread.h> // for pthread
#include <string.h> // for memset
    
#define TIMEOUT 10


pthread_t tid1, tid2;

void* thread_function1(void *arg)
{
    while(1) 
    {
        printf(" thread_function1 invoked\n");
        sleep(1); //avoid heavy prints 
    }
}

void* thread_function2(void *arg)
{
    while(1)
    {
        printf(" thread_function2 invoked\n");
        sleep(1); //avoid heavy prints
    }
}   

static void timer_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context)
{
    printf("Inside handler function timeout happened \n");
    if( sig == SIGALRM)
    {
        pthread_cancel(tid1);
        pthread_cancel(tid2);
        //exit(0); to exit from main
    }
}

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    void *status;
    
    struct sigaction act;
    memset (&act, '\0', sizeof(act));
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    /* Use the sa_sigaction field because the handles has two additional parameters */
    act.sa_sigaction = timer_handler;
    /* The SA_SIGINFO flag tells sigaction() to use the sa_sigaction field, not sa_handler. */
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    if (sigaction(SIGALRM, &act, NULL) < 0)
    {
        perror ("sigaction SIGALRM");
        return 1;
    }
    alarm (TIMEOUT);
    pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,thread_function1,NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid2,NULL,thread_function2,NULL);

    pthread_join(tid1,NULL);
    pthread_join(tid2,NULL);
    printf(" MIAN ENDS ...BYE BYE \n");
    return 0;
}
```